# any idea how to change default location of .vimrc for droidvim on unrooted android ver.10?

Tags: terminal

I wonder if it is possible/how to change the .vimrc location to a different location (eg: my sync folder), so that i can back it up often and easily to manjaro pc using ssh or rsync.

The original location is said in [$INTERNAL_STORAGE]/android/data/data.droidvim/ folder.. but after my android upgraded from 8 to 10, i can no longer access to "internal_storage" nor "/android" folder.